# Javascript click event on html5 canvas not working

Tags: javascript, html, events

I'm making a website for a school project, but for some reason, a javascript click element isn't working... [Here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/48890691/index.html)'s a link to the full website.

Here are some gists, which will probably be more up date than the website itself.

[index.html](https://gist.github.com/1878266)
[canvas.js](https://gist.github.com/1878280)

Please help, thanks.

Comment: please make a jsfiddle at www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: You are binding the `click` event handler before the element is available. Every DOM manipulation has to go inside `$(function() {...})`.

Comment: Woah, thanks! That really helped, I was already getting desperate! Go ahead and "answer" the question so I can credit you =D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do as follows:

```
    can = document.getElementById("canvas")  //get canvas element
    can.addEventListener('click', function_name, false) //register event


   function function_name(e) //handle event
   {
       //your code for click event

   }
```